# Unable to set UIlabel text - Swift

Tags: swift

I have custom UIView class where is have defined all my outlets, I need to change the texts from the information in dictionaries. Unable to do so help please.

/* THIS IS THE UIVIEW CLASS WHERE I WANT TO CHANGE THE TEXTS OF THE UILABEL. */

```
import UIKit
var alertAnimator : ReferAnimatorAlert = ReferAnimatorAlert()
class ReferAnimatorAlert : UIView
{
var detailArray : Array<NSMutableDictionary>!
@IBOutlet var alertView : UIView!
@IBOutlet var cellView1 : UIView!
@IBOutlet var cellView2 : UIView!

@IBOutlet var itemImage1 : UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var itemImage2 : UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var profileImage1 : UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var profileImage2 : UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel1 : UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel2 : UILabel!

@IBOutlet var descriptionLabel1 : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var descriptionLabel2 : UILabel!

@IBOutlet var separatorView1 : UIView!
@IBOutlet var separatorView2 : UIView!

@IBOutlet var dismissOutlet : UIButton!

//MARK : - IBActions Declaration
@IBAction func dismissAction(sender : UIButton)
{

}


func setDetails()
{
    for aDictionary in detailArray
    {
        if aDictionary["isHas"] as! Bool == true
        {
            usernameLabel2.text = aDictionary["Name"] as? String
            descriptionLabel2.text = aDictionary["description"] as? String
        }
        else
        {
            //usernameLabel1.text = aDictionary["Name"] as? String
            self.usernameLabel1.text = "This is a test."
            //descriptionLabel1.text = aDictionary["description"] as? String
        }
    }

    Animator.animateAlertCells(cellView1, cellView2: cellView2, alertView: alertView, dismissOutlet: dismissOutlet)
}
```

//THIS IS HOW  I'M PASSING THE DATA FROM ANOTHER VIEWCONTROLLER.

```
var predicate : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "isHighlighted == %@", true)
var resultDictionary = responseArray.filter(){predicate.evaluateWithObject($0)}
println(resultDictionary)
alertAnimator.detailArray = resultDictionary
overlayView.hidden = false
alertAnimator.setDetails()
```

The program breaks at ' usernameX.text = "Blah Blah" '

Comment: what does your `resultDictionary` include? can u add that too in the question.

Comment: [{
    Name = "Matthew Jason";
    description = "I'm screwed.";
    isHas = 0;
    isHighlighted = 1;
    item = Driver;
    "item-image" = "";
    "user-image" = "";
}, {
    Name = "John Mayer";
    description = "He doesnt wants to stay single";
    isHas = 1;
    isHighlighted = 1;
    item = "Car to sell.";
    "item-image" = "";
    "user-image" = "";
}]

Comment: By breaks, do you mean unable to compile? Or the program crashes when reaching that statement? Could you post the error message you receive?

Comment: its says "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

Comment: Where do you call setDetails method ? Im pretty sure that `usernameX` is nil

Comment: usernameX is just a UILabel. I haven't initialised any value to it. But, when I try to set it to aDictionary["Name"] as? String. It doesn't set the value it crashes the program. I have used storyboards and set the class of a view as ReferAnimatorAlert, which is subclass of UIView. And then I have linked the IBOutlets to the labels on the view.